# xrandr multiple screens not working

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xorg, xrandr

Yesterday I updated Arch Linux (Kernel: 5.10.3-arch1-1) and now I have a strange issue with xrandr.
The second monitor is not working. `xrandr` shows me that HDMI is connected and shows available resolutions. `xrandr --listmonitors` does detect it:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors

Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP1 1920/340x1080/190+0+0  eDP1

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm

1920x1080     59.98*+  59.93
...
640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00


VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-0 disconnected
DP-1-1 disconnected
DP-1-2 disconnected
DP-1-3 disconnected
HDMI-1-0 connected
   1440x900      59.89 +  74.98
   1920x1080     59.94
   1280x720      59.94
...
```

With `arandr` I can find the screen on HDMI but when I try to activate it, it gives me this error:

```
XRandr failed:
Xrandr returned error code 1:b'
xrandr: Configure crtc 4 failed
X error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
 Major opcode of failed request: 140 (RANDR)
 Minor opcode of failed request: 21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
 Value in failed request: 0x0
 Serial number of failed request: 69
 Current serial number in output stream 69
```

Output of `xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --auto`:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 4 failed
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  68
  Current serial number in output stream:  68
```

Can anyone help? Thank you so much

If it's useful, this is the output of `xrandr --listproviders`:

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x220 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

Comment: Seems like other people are facing [the same problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1946837). The issue will probably be fixed in a future kernel update.

Comment: If it's an option, I'd try switching to the LTS kernel, which is currently on version 5.4.86.

Comment: I switched to LTS kernel as suggested and now it's back to work. However, I wonder if it is a bug of the kernel or there is a solution by playing with settings. Thank you for your help